# KVO: How to observe plain pointers?

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

We've been using KVO to track some changes in objects. Recently we changed code to c++ to put it into a multi-platform library.

This left us with some properties that are now pointers to c++ objects, but the same reasoning would hold for, say an `void *`, or any pointer to what's not a true Objective-C object.

So basically we have

```
@property (nonatomic) void *value;
```

There are several problems arising:

- No change notifications are generated automatically.

This can be handled by implementing the setter manually, i.e.

```
-(void)setValue:(void *)value {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"value"];
    _value = value;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"value"];
}
```

- The class is not KVO-compliant for the key.

This seems natural, as it's not clear how to put the custom data into some object to pass along. This breaks observers that ask for old or new data in the change dictionary. Again, one can help oneself here and wrap things up manually:

```
-(id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key {
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"value"])
        return [NSValue valueWithPointer:_value];
    return [super valueForKey:key];
}
```

So having sorted out some glitches, I wonder if there are more pitfalls to look out for. Or are there some best practices in that regard?